# What is the best view architecture in flex?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, view, states, viewstack

I have started learning flex 4 and I got myself thinking about how to change views. So I have a question what do people usually use - states or views (ViewStack). The type of web application I am making, can use both, but what do developers use in big projects or maybe they use non of the mentioned before?

Also I have a question about ViewStack. If I write:

```
<mx:ViewStack id="views" resizeToContent="true" verticalCenter="0" horizontalCenter="0" >
    <s:NavigatorContent id="navOne">
        <s:Label text="asdas" x="0" y="0"/>
    </s:NavigatorContent>
```

then I can't change location of its child. Label remains in the center of the screen. If I remove vertical and horizontal center from ViewStack and put them in Label's tags, then label will be in top left corner but not in center. How do I control those locations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as you're using Flex 4 you can prefer states. And there are at least two reasons for that:

1. Flex 4 states are much more declarative than in Flex 3.
2. Flex 4 hasn't Spark implementation of `ViewStack` and it is rather obsolete (necessarity of using `NavigatorContent` with Spark container is another proof of that fact).

The second part of the question. The problem is your `ViewStack` hasn't any size. So finally it has size of content (`Label` size). So `verticalCenter` and `horizontalCenter` are just alignment of your `ViewStack`. To control size and alignment of `ViewStack` you should care about sizes. Something like:

```
<mx:ViewStack id="views" resizeToContent="true" verticalCenter="0" 
    horizontalCenter="0" width="500" height="300" >
    <s:NavigatorContent id="navOne" width="100%" height="100%">
        <s:Label text="asdas" x="0" y="0"/>
    </s:NavigatorContent>
```

Comment: If using Flex 4, I only use states as I don't see the point of using viewstacks that does exactly the same thing.  If you wanted to, I'm sure you could create a spark Viewstack equivalent in a few dozen lines of code.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. + thanks for help with second question, now it works as I intended.